# How to remove decimals if number is a whole number in VBScript?

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am using VBScript to enter data into an excel worksheet.

```
objWorksheet.Cells(1, 1) = 1
```

When I run this code and open the worksheet, the excel file displays 1.0. I would like it to only display 1

```
objWorksheet.Cells(1, 1) = 1.5
```

When I run this code and open the worksheet, the excel file displays 1.5, which is the desired behavior.

How can I remove the ".0" so that only the whole number is displayed in VBScript?

Comment: It's probably the number format of the cell and has nothing to do with scripting.  Also, is this VBScript, or VBA?

Comment: This is vbscript. And I know how to do this in excel using the truncate function, but I can't seem to find an equivalent in vbscript.

Comment: Why would you want it to display a different number of decimal places?  Usually if there are any numbers that have decimal places, you want them all rounded to the same number of decimal places.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not my decision to choose, otherwise I would agree. However it turns out I was able to solve this in excel. I used conditional formatting and created a new rule using a formula =TRUNC(5.3, 1) = 5.3. I'm not sure why this works though...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function for you:

```
Function GetTruncatedWholeNumber(sngToTruncate)
    Dim intTruncated
    intTruncated = CInt(sngToTruncate)
    sngToTruncate = CSng(sngToTruncate) 'just to make sure it's a single.

    If(sngToTruncate = intTruncated) Then _
        GetTruncatedWholeNumber = intTruncated Else _
        GetTruncatedWholeNumber = sngToTruncate
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but unfortunately it confirms what you said in your first comment about it having nothing to do with scripting. If you look at my last comment I found a wacky solution that I don't understand the workings of. In Excel, I select a range of cells, and use conditional formatting to create a new rule, and use a formula to determine which cells to format. In the "Format values where this formula is true" box, I type "=TRUNC(5.3, 1) = 5.3". The 5.3 is completely arbitrary. This works for some cells but not for all. Do you know how I could fix it?

Comment: No, unfortunately I'm more of a scripting wizard and less of a plain Excel wizard.